# aggregation mongodb, return all subdocument after match

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I have the collections books, with the following data:

```
books: {
  title: "Mickey",
  subtitle: "The Mouse",
  authors: [
    {
      name: "Walt Disney",
      type: "Author"
    },
    {
      name: "Donald Duffy",
      type: "Co-Author"
    },
    categories: [
      "kids, education"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is after `$unwind` my authors array and then `$match` with `$regex` for coincidences if the field autor.name has whatever string I am sending, for example

```
$match: { "author.name": {$regex: ".*walt.*", $options: "si"}, title: "Mickey"}
```

then after `$group` and `$push` my array, I end up with

```
books: {
  title: "Mickey",
  subtitle: "The Mouse",
  authors: [
    {
      name: "Walt Disney",
      type: "Author"
    }, categories: [
      "kids, education"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Is there a way or operator in mongodb to keep all my subdocuments after a matching a field, the reason why I want this, is because on the front-end of my app every author and category would be a link to all the books that have that name or category and I want to display all of them.

Comment: I believe you have a mistake in your data entry, is that right? `{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e0ded6c9b761bd44a13f7"), 
    "title" : "Mickey", 
    "subtitle" : "The Mouse", 
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name" : "Walt Disney", 
            "type" : "Author"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Donald Duffy", 
            "type" : "Co-Author"
        }
    ], 
    "categories" : [
        "kids, education"
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to include “Donald Duffy” as in your initial document? If so you can use simple `find` by making use of the **dot notation** so you won’t have to use aggregation. `db.collection.find({"authors.name": {$regex: ".*walt.*", $options: "si"}, "title": "Mickey"})`

The same with aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "authors.name": {$regex: ".*walt.*", $options: "si"}, 
    "title": "Mickey"
  }
}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to do it with agreggation :/

Comment: @OttoCheley `$match` is the equivalent to `find`. I updated the answer with the use of aggregation framework

Comment: I will give it a shot :). Thank you

Comment: Dude you are a heroe that I don't deserve thank you very much my friend. This solved my problem :)

Comment: @OttoCheley no problem mate ;)